# Codeigniter: Checking to see if config variable is set?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Wondering if there is a way to check if a config variable is set in Codeigniter?

```
if ( isset($this->config->item('configItem'))) {
//do stuff
}
```

Seems like something like this should work? The error I get is "Expected: variable".

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Are you loading your config file?**

```
$this->config->load('configfilename');
```

If you are loading it then you should use:

```
if ( $this->config->item('configItem')) {
   //do stuff
}
```

The config class in CodeIgniter already handles the isset() and returns false if it can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if ( isset($this->config->item('configItem'))&&($this->config->item('configItem')!='')) {
{
  //Proceed with your Code
}
```